# Making a compound adjective using "mundane" and "oriented"

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

In compound modifiers, we sometimes use nouns instead of adjectives, however, I do not know which one is the correct choice in the sentences below:

> However, one can claim that such an inspiration, in alignment with scientist’s chain of thoughts, is something **mundane-oriented** which naturally occurs in a due time when, e.g., specific amounts of information or knowledge are deepened or combined to a critical point.

Or

> However, one can claim that such an inspiration, in alignment with scientist’s chain of thoughts, is something **mundanity-oriented** which naturally occurs in a due time when, e.g., specific amounts of information or knowledge are deepened or combined to a critical point.

I also want to know if in the above sentences we have a choice to use "**at** a critical point" instead of "**to** a critical point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mundanity-oriented" makes no sense! It should be "mundane-oriented".

"At a critical point" cannot be used here as the context depicts something deepening *until* a point.

> until a point -> up to a point -> to a point